# PCL Color Filter

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want to filter out the points in a point cloud with a certain 'r' value.

I looked at the documentation, and noticed pcl/filters/color.h is no longer available in PCL 1.7 and above, which is puzzling. (http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.3.1/classpcl_1_1_color_filter.html).

I can probably do this with a naive for loop, but was wondering if there is a way using the pass-through filter conditions, as that is probably multithreaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using conditional_removal, there is a template specialization for RGB. Here is a snippet where we get a ROS point cloud called cloud_msg.

```
 #include <pcl/filters/conditional_removal.h> //and the other usuals

 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr rgb_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
 pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud_msg, *rgb_cloud);
 pcl::PCLPointCloud2 cloud_filtered_ros;

 pcl::ConditionalRemoval<pcl::PointXYZRGB> color_filter;

 pcl::PackedRGBComparison<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr
     red_condition(new pcl::PackedRGBComparison<pcl::PointXYZRGB>("r", pcl::ComparisonOps::GT, 90));
 pcl::ConditionAnd<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr color_cond (new pcl::ConditionAnd<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ());
 color_cond->addComparison (red_condition);

 // Build the filter
 color_filter.setInputCloud(rgb_cloud);
 color_filter.setCondition (color_cond);
 color_filter.filter(*cloud_filtered)
```